# websites are not loading in chrome but they work fine in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, browser, proxy

Every page I try to go to in chrome says "This webpage is not available" but websites work fine in other browsers.

I recently installed http://www.getwindmill.com/ just to experiment. I think my problem has to do with proxy settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

windmill created a proxy that chrome and safari follow.

go to system preferences | network | Advanced | Proxies and uncheck the web proxy check box.